# Extended existing ASP.NET CORE Web API without recompilation

Tags: asp.net-core

Is it possible Extended existing ASP.NET CORE Web API without recompilation.

e.g existing API works on "mysite.com/API/Controler1/Method1" want to add new controller "mysite.com/API/Controler1/Method2", without recompilation and stooping existing server.

whole idea is, not touching things that's working.

Should I split project in to two project ? (In that case how to deal with routing ?)

Comment: This depends on a lot of things that you haven't told us, like how much of the application runs on the server.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38298312

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36121999

Comment: Every time when I Update my server application (webAPI) with new functionality I have to stop everlasting recompile it and redeploy.

It would be nice to have ability to deploy new controlers for existing asp.net application without recompiling it.

Comment: That would be a neat trick.  C# is a compiled language.  The only way to do it would be to dynamically compile some code for each web request.  There are ways to do that, but it would take some time to work out a good solution, and there are performance penalties.

Comment: Have a look here for some ideas: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt808499.aspx