# Call and listen for temporary endpoint, inside asp.net minimal api

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am stuck with something, that I don't know if it is even possible. Basically the idea is to have an endpoint that when it is called, it generates and listens a temporary endpoint for 45seconds, and if this gets "requested" to finalise the function.

I generated the following code block:

```
app.MapPost("/dataid/supplier/listen", async (Supplier supplier) =>

{
    var listener = new HttpListener();

    listener.Prefixes.Add($"https://localhost:7147/dataid/supplier/{supplier.token}/");

    listener.Start();

    HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();

    HttpListenerRequest requesti = context.Request;

    for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++)

    {

        if (context.Response != null)

        {

            HttpListenerResponse response = context.Response;

            Console.WriteLine(response.ContentLength64);

            listener.Stop();

            return Results.Ok(new { token = "2" });

        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        Console.WriteLine(i);

        i++;

    }

    listener.Stop();

    return Results.Ok(new { token = "1" });


});
```

however, when I try to run it, it tells me that the domain is endpoint is already being used.

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
      An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
      System.Net.HttpListenerException (48): Address already in use
         at System.Net.HttpEndPointManager.GetEPListener(String host, Int32 port, HttpListener listener, Boolean secure)
```

Any help?

Comment: Some cursory searching didn't avail anything to me, but if this was a problem I had, I'd write a general endpoint that was always live for `dataid/supplier/{supplier.token}/` and use a singleton service to provided the effective behavior and just send 404s for things that shouldn't exist.

Comment: This is getting a bit into the vein of what you want using a `RouteConstraint` that uses a service https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298312/dynamic-routing-in-asp-net-core

Comment: The problem is that the supplier.token will be thousands of tokens, and really impossible to set it at the server start moment. I need something that basically creates endpoints on the fly, and if they are called, to react, if not, to send a non-react. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: You should read the ASP.NET documentation.  Pattern matching is supported for endpoints.  You don't need to know them up front.