# How to create dynamic routes in ASP.NET Core 7

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-7.0

I am trying to create a route dynamically for the request. The examples I have found online don't work.

I have 2 actions at:

```
MyApp.Areas.Buyer.Controllers.SocialController.Index 
MyApp.Areas.Client.Controllers.SocialController.Index
```

I am trying to create a route that loads those actions depending on a condition from the `HttpContext`.

One of the solutions I have tried is to use a `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` and create the a route dynamically and pass in the controller, action and other parameters if necessary. But my transformer is not working as expected and I am not sure whether it is the right use for this.

I create and register the `RouteValueTransformer` in `Program.cs` like this:

```
app.MapDynamicControllerRoute<HomeDynamicRouteValueTransformer>("/");
```

This is what the transformer looks like:

```
public class HomeDynamicRouteValueTransformer : DynamicRouteValueTransformer, IHomeDynamicRouteValueTransformer
{
    public override ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(
        HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
    {
        if (httpContext.Request.Path == "/")
        {
            values = new RouteValueDictionary();
            // return new ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary>(values);

            values["controller"] = "SocialController";
            values["action"] = "Get";
            values["id"] = "id";
        }

        return new ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary>(values);
    }
}
```

The `RouteValueDictionary` values in `TransformAsync` are always null. I thought that is supposed to have data. But even that does not work when I create a new `RouteValueDictionary` and return it.

Comment: Have a look at[Dynamic routing in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298312/dynamic-routing-in-asp-net-core) .   And if  you want a different page on the home page depending on the type of user, you can try to use  `User.IsInRole` to determine the current role.  you can have a look at [View-based authorization in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/views?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know more.